# Dynamically creating buttons in html with mysql row value

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, dynamic

I am drawing all my information from my sql database and displaying it in a table in html. I want to be able to click on a button at the end of each row, or somewhere on the row, and display another set of things relating to the uniqueID in that row. However at the moment, the value does not change for each dynamically created button.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Hybrid";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<table><tr><th>ID</th><th>Timestamp</th><th>Rate</th><th>Fiat</th><th>BTC</th><th>BTCadd</th><th>Contact</th><th>PaymentMethod</th><th>Bank</th><th>localprofile</th><th>BTname</th><th>uniqID</th><th>Confirm2</th><th>Paymentmade</th><th>Paymenttime</th></tr>";
    // output data of each row
    while ($row = $result-> fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr><td>".$row["ID"].
        "</td><td>".date('d-m H:i', strtotime($row["Timestamp"])).
        "</td><td>".$row["Rate"].
        "</td><td>".$row["Fiat"].
        "</td><td>".$row["BTC"].
        "</td><td>".$row["BTCadd"].
        "</td><td>".$row["Contact"].
        "</td><td>".$row["PaymentMethod"].
        "</td><td>".$row["Bank"].
        "</td><td>".$row["localprofile"].
        "</td><td>".$row["BTname"].
        "</td><td>".$row["uniqID"].
        "</td><td>".$row["Confirm2"].
        "</td><td>".$row["Paymentmade"].
        "</td><td>".date('d-m H:i', $row["Paymenttime"]).
        "</td><td>".
        "<button id='view' type='button' value='$row[uniqID]' onclick='dropdown();' >View</button>".
        "</td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
}
```

This bit is the button:

```
 <td>" . "<button id='view' type='button' value='$row[uniqID]' onclick='dropdown();' >View</button>" . "</td>
```

and $row['uniqID'] displays all the different uniqIDs on my table in html, however, when I try this in javascript:

```
<script>
    var id = document.getElementById("view").value;

    function dropdown() {
        alert(id);
    };
</script>
```

It only alerts the first `$row['uniqID']` regardless of which button I press, instead of the one corresponding to the row.

I need the value of the button to correspond to the uniqueID for that row, so I can use it in the button function, maybe there is another way?

I am stuck as to how to do this, I thought it might be something to do with the 'infamous javascript loop issue' but I am not sure if it applies, or if it does quite how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`id` is to be unique, but you have n number of `id='view'`. So since there should only be 1 `id='view'` javascript will find the first one only. You could add `this.value` to the function call -

```
"<td>" . 
"<button id='view' type='button' value='$row[uniqID]' onclick='dropdown(this.value);' >View</button>" .
"</td>"
```

and then use that in your function

```
<script>
 function dropdown(id){
     alert(id);
 }
</script>
```

Comment: DON! Thankyou would not have realised that myself! Very useful! Thanks all fixed :o)